# Animation completes immediately iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, animation

I am creating an app where there is a main view managed by a view controller and a second view for settings managed by another view controller.

I am using a Container View Controller for UI/UX reasons in an app where after touching a button, the view for the settings slides up from the bottom of the screen to about mid-height. The top half of the screen still shows the previous main view.

Everything is working perfectly, after pressing the button or when the user dismisses the View Controller that slid up, I keep one of the view (because it is still visible), I keep the view controller in memory but I remove it from the View Controller hierarchy and switch to the other one.

The problem now is that when I press the button to show the settings view controller, all the very simple animations on the main view, such as animating the frame property of a UILabel, behave unexpectedly. The animation complete almost immediately.

I read an answer on StackOverflow pointing at the fact that changing the transform property makes it impossible to animate using the frame property and requires to animate witht the center property.

Even though I haven’t explicitely changed the transform property of any objects (I am not very familiar with this property), I tried to animate using the center property and it still animated too fast.

Here is an example of an animation that completes immediately after the settings button is pressed but works fine otherwise:

```
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.4 animations:^{

            self.alarmTimeLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.alarmTimeLabel.center.x, self.alarmTimeLabel.center.y + 200);


        }];
```

Thanks for any input

Comment: somehow... this animation is in viewDidLoad of the second controller? This behavior ...also... may occur if the label is already animated

Comment: The animation happen in the first view controller, the one for the main UI. It's when user go back to the main UI after the visiting the settings menu that the first UI doesn't animate properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animations now work using an older method to achieve the same result.

```
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"test" context:nil];

        [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];

        self.alarmTimeLabel.center = centerAlarmTimeLabel;
        self.amOrPm.center = centerAmOrPm;



        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

That fixed the bug! I don't know why the newer way to make simple animations doesn't work, even when using the center property.